# Select distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MYSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`user_id`), `type`, `link`, `add_text`
FROM `activity`  WHERE `id` != 0 AND `type` !=6 AND (`type` = 4 OR `type` = 5)
ORDER BY `id` DESC  LIMIT 4
```

I only want unique `user_id`s but I am getting repetitions in my sql results. What is the correct modification to make to this sql so that no repetitions of `user_id`s

Comment: in activity, is the combination of user_Id, type, link and add_text unique?  if so, then you'll have user_ID's replicated.  Which type do you want?  what Link do you want? what add_text do you want for the single USER_ID you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the types, links or add text for each user you could use min/max and group by.

```
SELECT user_id, max(type), max(link), max(add_text)
FROM activity
WHERE id != 0 A
AND type in (4,5) 
Group by User_Id 
ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 4
```

If you do care you could group_concat the type, link and add text

```
SELECT user_id, Group_Concat(type), Group_Concat(link), Group_Concat(add_text) 
FROM activity
WHERE id != 0 A
AND type in (4,5) 
Group by User_Id
ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 4
```

edied group by shoudl only be on user_ID

Comment: I get a BLOB for type and there are repeated user_ids

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user_id`) user_ids, `type`, `link`, `add_text`
FROM `activity`
WHERE `id` != 0 AND `type` IN (4,5)
GROUP BY `type`, `link`, `add_text` DESC  LIMIT 4;
```